# Create threads throw Segmentation fault eror

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Im try to write program that create 2 threads, that first thread will print all the even numbers from 0 to number and the second thread will print all the odd numbers from 1 to the same number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* printOddNumbers(void* maxNumbers);
void* printEvenNumbers(void* maxNumbers);

int main(){
    pthread_t oddNumbersThread;
    pthread_t evenNumbersThread;
    int maxNumber = 20;
    pthread_create(&oddNumbersThread, NULL, printOddNumbers, (void *)maxNumber);
    pthread_create(&evenNumbersThread, NULL, printEvenNumbers, (void *)maxNumber);
    printf("Main thread1 finished");
    return 0;
}

void* printOddNumbers(void* maxNumbers){
    int *maxNumber = (int *)maxNumber;
    int currentNumber = 1;
    while(currentNumber <= *maxNumber){
        sleep(1);
        printf("Odd: %d", currentNumber);
        currentNumber += 2;
    } 
}
void* printEvenNumbers(void* maxNumbers){
    int *maxNumber = (int *)maxNumber;
    int currentNumber = 0;
    while(currentNumber <= *maxNumber){
        sleep(1);
        printf("Evem: %d", currentNumber);
        currentNumber += 2;
    } 
}
```

when i run the program, it return Segmentation fault, and i dont undetstand why because im not trying to access any unauthorized memory from inside the threads. Thanks !

Comment: For problems like this, it's super helpful to use a debugger (for instance gdb) - that'd tell you exactly where the segmentation fault is happening in your code. In this case, I'd expect the reason to be that your casting the *value* of `maxNumber` to `void*` rather than casting the address of if?

Comment: @sonicwave im not sure that i understood how to do the casting of the args to pass it into the thread

Comment: what do you suppose happens when you do `*(int*)maxNumber` i.e. read `int` from address 20?

Comment: `(void *)maxNumber` -> `(void *)&maxNumber`. You should have read the compiler warnings.

Comment: Or, even better, `(void *)maxNumber` -> `&maxNumber` (without any cast).  C has implicit conversion from all object pointer types to type `void *`, and any cast for other than arithmetic purposes has bad code smell.  Note also that it's only so simple because the threads don't modify `maxNumber` via the provided pointer.  More would be needed if they wanted to do that.